# Add pre-cached images in apk file for use with Picasso or similar library

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I am using Picasso for retrieving and showing images in my Android app. To avoid downloading all images over the network I am trying to add some images with the apk file, as sort of a pre-cached set of images. These images are stored in the assets folder and then copied to the Picasso cache folder on installation. This works as expected, but Picasso still download all images through the network and caches them as `.0` and `.1` files like this:

```
root@generic_x86:/data/data/com.my.app/files/images_cache #
ls
10.JPG
100.JPG
101.JPG
102.JPG
11.JPG
1f94664dec9a8c205b7dc50f8a6f3b79.0
1f94664dec9a8c205b7dc50f8a6f3b79.1
2.JPG
4621206beccad87a0fc01df2d080c644.0
4621206beccad87a0fc01df2d080c644.1
```

The `*.JPG` images are the ones I copied and the others are the Picasso cached images. Is there a way to make Picasso cache these images properly on installation?

If not, are there any other similar libraries that supports this kind of pre-caching?

## Update: trying to cache from Assets folder

I tried making a small snippet that is run at first run of the app. The idea is to iterate the files in the given assets folder and fetch those images with Picasso. However, the below does not cache anything, although I end up in the `onSuccess()` method of the callback. The asset file names are correct. This is also verified by using the wrong folder name, which puts me in the `onError()` method of the callback.

I also tried loading it into a temporary `ImageView`, but it did do any difference.

```
public static boolean cacheImagesFromAssetsFolder(Context context)
{
    boolean ok = false;

    try
    {
        String[] images = context.getAssets().list("my_images");
        for (String image : images)
        {
            Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/my_images/" + image).fetch(new Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess()
                {
                    // This is where I end up. Success, but nothing happens.
                }

                @Override
                public void onError()
                {

                }
            });
        }
        ok = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ok;
}
```

Comment: When it downloads any image it remembers this hash and make a key from it for caching.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could find the hash and hash all the images, or create a temporary `ImageView` and load every image into this to force Picasso to cache the images, but it feels more like a hack than anything else. Therefore, I am wondering if there are any built-in solutions for it.

Comment: You can improve this hack just fetching em, it's not necessary to add them to the image view

Answer (score 0):

You could use File URI to request the Picasso to pick the image from your asset location instead of n/w.

```
  Picasso.with(activity) //
                .load(Uri.fromFile(file)) // Location of the image from asset folder
```

**Update: How to use your own cache**

```
import com.squareup.picasso.LruCache;
import com.squareup.picasso.Util;
LruCache imageCache = new LruCache(context);
Request request = Request.Builder(Uri.fromFile(asset_file), 0, null).build();
String cacheKey = Util.createKey(request, new StringBuilder());
imageCache.set(cacheKey, bitmap_object_of_asset_image);
Picasso.Builder(context)
       .memoryCache(imageCache)
       .build().load(asset_url).fetch(callback);
```

Comment: Well, I tried doing something like this, see the updated post. I am wondering, however: Even if I can make this work, will fetching the file from the Assets directory make the hash the same as for getting it over the network? I mean, from the assets folder I use `"file:///android_asset/my_images/my_file.JPG"`, but for the network paths I use `http://this/is/my/network/path/image.JPG`.

Comment: No, the key is built based the URI you pass, which means if you make n/w call for the same image that is in asset folder, you would end up fetching the image from n/w. To overcome this you have to build your own MemoryCache and inject it to Picasso. You could use Util.createKey() to build your cache. Which means you have to have cache key both for asset folder and n/w URI.